# jquery get html from custom elements without closing tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I define custome html elements like below:

```
<div class="test">
    <myelement1 class="elclass" />
    <myelement2 class="elclass" >
    <myelement3 class="elclass"> my html </myelement3>
</div>
```

and get html of them by jquery code:

```
var elementHtml = "";
$('.test').find(".elclass").each(function(){elementHtml += "my element html: " + $(this).html();});
alert(elementHtml);
```

it works fine with the myelement3 but it's not work properly with myelement1 and myelement2.
How to get html from myelement1 and myelement2? I know that if it works fine, html of myelement1 and myelement2 will be null.

**Update:**

I know myelement2 is not standard but in html there are some elements like myelement1 and myelement2. For example:
`<input>` you can also write `<input/>`, `<img>` or `<img/>`.
I want to create custom elements in three types:

```
1.<tagname>
2.<tagname/>
3.<tagname></tagname>
```

I also know myelement1 and myelement2 html are empty but I want to get html from them.
Is there a way to get html for all of above types of custom elements?

Comment: probably because you're using a self-closing tag on the first two...

Comment: seems like a no-brainer to just close the tags

Comment: Self closing elements are defined in the Document Type Definition (DTD), you can't just make up your own self closing elements and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put the `/` at the end of your `myelement2` tag:

```
<div class="test">
    <myelement1 class="elclass" />
    <myelement2 class="elclass" /> 
    <myelement3 class="elclass"> my html </myelement3>
</div>
```

Comment: `//` comments are not valid in HTML.  It would be better to write a full explanation before the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close myelement2.

Also myelement1 and myelement2 html are empty